# Apache2 Vhosts and DnsMasq, unable to access website from another computer over LAN : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, local-area-network, dnsmasq

I'm currently setting up a web server over my LAN to satisfy some needs like using Phabricator or other intranet services. To do this, I installed apache2, php5, mysql and DNSMASQ which allows me to manage a DHCP and DNS server. But now I'm stucked with virtual hosts that are working just fine over the local machine but cannot be accessed from another computer on the local network, I'm getting "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

To test my settings, I declared a virtual host like this :

Creating the root folder of our website

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/www/test.devbox/public_html
$ chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.devbox/public_html
```

Placing an index file and add random text

```
$ nano /var/www/test.devbox/public_html/index.html
```

Now we create our virtual host file

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.devbox.conf
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.devbox.conf
```

Virtual Host Config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.devbox
    ServerName test.devbox
    ServerAlias www.test.devbox
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.devbox/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then we enable it using

```
$ sudo a2ensite test.devbox
```

Then I edited my hosts file to fit the servername directive in my test.devbox.config file (server side)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

192.168.1.254   bbox

127.0.1.1       MyPie
127.0.0.1       MyPie
127.0.0.1       devbox
127.0.0.1       opcv.devbox www.opcv.devbox
127.0.0.1       test.devbox www.test.devbox
```

Here is also my dnsmasq.conf file

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf

domain-needed
expand-hosts
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-poll
localise-queries
no-negcache

# DNS
#interface=eth0
local=/devbox/
domain=devbox

cache-size=10000

server=8.8.4.4
server=8.8.8.8
#server=194.158.122.10
#server=194.158.122.15

# DHCP
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=192.168.1.100,192.168.1.200,10h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.254
```

I then restarted everything

```
$ sudo reboot 
   or
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
$ sudo service apache2 reload/restart
```

And at this point I don't know where I should look, since the virtual host work locally but cannot be accessed from an other computer on the same network.

Using NSLOOKUP from an other machine I actually get

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup test.devbox
Server:   UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.10 (which is the server)

Nom :    test.devbox
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

And when I try to access http://test.devbox, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
I don't know where to look anymore.

Here is the answer of the apache2ctl command

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -S

AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:5
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost example.devbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.devbox.conf:1)
             alias www.example.devbox
     port 80 namevhost opcv.devbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/opcv.devbox.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost phabricator.devbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phabricator.devbox.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost test.devbox (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.devbox.conf:1)
             alias www.test.devbox
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Thank and I hope we'll be able to solve this issue together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, there was two problems.

1 : My dhcp server was still enabled on my router... (though I had already disabled it when I set up my dhcp and dns server...

2 : Indeed my DNSMASQ was wrongly configured. Now it is configured to redirect traffic with a peculiar domain (devbox here) to the apache server. I'm quite the newby, I understand what I did but I wouldn't be able to explain it. (Not a native speaker)

## dnsmasq.conf

```
#domain-needed not needed
no-hosts 
#expand-hosts not needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-poll
localise-queries
no-negcache

# DNS
#interface=eth0
#local=/lan/
#domain=lan
address=/devbox/192.168.1.10 -> This is the line redirecting traffic. 


cache-size=10000

server=8.8.4.4
server=8.8.8.8
#server=194.158.122.10
#server=194.158.122.15

# DHCP
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=192.168.1.100,192.168.1.200,10h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.254
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the output of nslookup you have you DNS entry configured wrong, it points test.devbox to 127.0.0.1. It should point to the 192.168.x.x IP of the server instead.

Once fixed this (As per your comments) to do what you want first you must ensure that each client machine that you want to navigate your sites uses your server for DNS resolution.

What happens is, on client machine A you open your browser and put:

```
http://test.devbox/
```

In the location bar.

The browser in client machine A asks the DNS server for test.devbox's IP address and get's 192.168.1.10 as a result.

The browser opens a TCP connection to 192.168.1.80 port 80 (HTTP) and send this request (I'm omitting uninteresting headers here):

```
GET / HTP/1.1
Host: test.devbox
[...]
```

The http server at that address responds as you've configured it.

So in short, if you're using separate Server and Client machines and want to use a FQDN instead if an IP to navigate your site, you either add the relevant entries at /etc/hosts of the machines (or equivalent under windows) or you ensure that both machines use a DNS server under your control. And no, 127.0.0.1 cant be accessed outside the local machine :-)

Comment: Well yeah I figured this out, but I don't know how and where I should configure this? If I just edited in my host file (server side) the (127.0.0.1  test.devbox) line to (192.168.1.10 test.devbox) the virtual host wouldn't work either. It'd be just the same as to type 192.168.1.10 in my web browser. :/

Comment: Well, it will work the same no? In your virtualhost you're listening on all interfaces (<VirtualHost  *:80>), and the other machine can resolve your domain name to the reachable one, 192.168.1.10

Comment: Even if didn't do this, the other machine could reach 192.168.1.10. The aim here is to have differents websites served from 192.168.1.10. To do this I used DNSMASQ and the host file hoping I could achieve my goal.

Comment: Replied in my answer, as it was long.

Comment: Yep thanks for your answer but as I said, the dns and dhcp servers works just fine and are used on each machine of the network. The thing here is that I can't just edit each machine's host file, that would be just wrong and too long. Ha and I know that 127.0.0.1 stands for localhost. But frankly speaking I'm just lost... I understood what you meant but I have no Idea as how to do this. What I'm almost certain is that Dnsmasq might be poorly configured. I'm gonna try some tweaks. I'll come back if I cannot figured it out. Thanks again by the way.

Comment: @Yoshino, if i recall correctly dnsmasq reads the /etc/hosts, so just putting the right entry in there should work, the entry should be: 192.168.1.10 test.devbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46132/discussion-between-yoshino-and-fredi).